# Disadvantages running TFS over HTTPS

Tags: tfs

We want to setup HTTPS for our TFS (on premise)

According to the documentation of Microsoft the disadvantages of requiring HTTPS for TFS are (besides some other disadvantages):

- You might complicate ongoing administration tasks. For example, you might have to reconfigure your deployment to stop supporting HTTPS with SSL before you can apply service packs or other updates.
- If you require HTTPS with SSL, your deployment's performance will be slower.

I can imagine that it will become a bit slower because of the encryption. I assume most environments are set up with HTTPS. 
Does someone really experience these kind of issues?

Comment: Using HTTPS is well-supported and recommended.  Indeed HTTPS is _slightly_ slower than HTTP with no encryption, but it's hard to imagine this _actually_ being a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The advantages and disadvantages have been listed in documentation [Setting up HTTPS with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer?view=tfs-2015):

> **Advantages of Supporting HTTPS with SSL in Addition to HTTP**
>
> If you configure your deployment of TFS to support both protocols,
>   users whose computers have been configured for HTTPS with SSL will
>   connect by using that protocol, which makes your deployment more
>   secure. In addition, users whose computers are configured for HTTP
>   only can still connect to your deployment. Although you should not
>   deploy this configuration over public networks, you can gain the
>   following advantages by continuing to support HTTP connections in a
>   controlled network environment:
>
> - You can increase the security of your deployment over time by    configuring client computers for HTTPS with SSL as your schedule
>     permits. If you take a phased approach, you do not need to upgrade
>     all computers at the same time, and users whose computers have not
>     yet been upgraded can still connect to the deployment.
> - You can more easily configure and maintain Team Foundation Server.
> - Calls from one Web service to another are faster over HTTP than over    HTTPS with SSL. Therefore, you can continue to support HTTP
>     connections from client computers for which the performance
>     requirements outweigh the security risks.
>
> **Advantages of Requiring HTTPS with SSL for All Connections**
>
> If you require HTTPS with SSL for all connections, you gain the
>   following advantages:
>
> - All web connections between the application tier, the data tier, and    the client tier for Team Foundation are more secure because
>     they    require certificates.
> - You can control access more easily by configuring certificates to    expire when a project phase is expected to end.
>
> **Disadvantages of Supporting or Requiring HTTPS with SSL**
>
> Before you configure TFS to support or require HTTPS with SSL, you
>   should consider the following disadvantages:
>
> - You might complicate ongoing administration tasks. For example, you    might have to reconfigure your deployment to stop supporting HTTPS
>     with SSL before you can apply service packs or other updates.
> - You must not only configure but also manage a certification authority    (CA) and certificate trusts. You can use Certificate
>     Services in    Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008, but you
>     might not want    to invest the time and resources that deploying a
>     secure public key    infrastructure (PKI) requires.
> - You must spend significant time setting up and testing either of    these configurations, and troubleshooting your deployment will become 
>     more difficult.
> - If you continue to support both protocols, external connections might    not be encrypted if the application tier for Team Foundation
>     is not    appropriately secured.
> - If you require HTTPS with SSL, your deployment's performance will be    slower.

Using HTTPS makes your deployment more secure, and as *@Edward* mentioned, using HTTPS is well-supported and recommended. Indeed HTTPS is slightly slower than HTTP with no encryption, but it's hard to imagine this actually being a problem. If you meet any issue using HTTPS, you could open a new case with detailed information so that we can provide better support.